# ¿Como puedo obtener el valor maximo de un registro?

Tags: sql-server

Quisiera obtener el valor maximo de un registro(en este caso la FechaConsulta), ya que un registro se duplica y quisiera que en mi SP no me devolviera los registros duplicados, no lo puedo hacer con un DISTINCT porque el campo de Contador es diferente para cada registo, por eso quisiera obtener el valor maximo de la fecha para asi solo mostrar uno por cada uno, traigo los registro mediante un SELECT, para posteriormente mostrarlo en una tabla desde Visual Studio

```
SELECT

    RCCE_NID AS RecetaId,
    CASE (RCCE_ESTATUS) WHEN '0' THEN 'Recepción Vitamedica' ELSE 'Cotizar' END AS Estatus,
    RCCE_NOMBRES + ' ' + RCCE_APELLIDO_PATERNO + ' ' + RCCE_APELLIDO_MATERNO AS Derechohabiente,
    RCCE_ELEGIBILIDAD AS Elegibilidad,
    RCCE_FOLIO_RECETA AS FolioReceta,
    RCCE_TANTO_RECETA AS TantoReceta,
    RCCE_CODIGO_EAN AS CodigoEAN,
    RCCE_DESCRIPCION_MEDICAMENTO AS DescripcionMedicamento,
    RCCE_UNIDADES AS Unidades,
    RCCE_PREAUTORIZACION AS Preautorizacion,
    RCCE_FECHA_CONSULTA AS FechaConsulta,
    RCCE_COPAGO AS Copago,
    CASE (RCCE_TIPO_EMPLEADO) WHEN '0' THEN 'Funcionario' ELSE 'Empleado' END AS TipoEmpleado,
    CASE (RCCE_STATUS_EMPLEADO) WHEN '0' THEN 'Activo' ELSE 'Jubilado' END AS EstatusEmpleado,
    RCCE_NUMERO_TELEFONO AS NumeroTelefono,
    CASE (RCCE_TIPO_TELEFONO) WHEN '0' THEN 'Fijo' ELSE 'Móvil' END AS TipoTelefono,
    RCCE_CANTIDAD_TOMA AS CantidadToma,
    RCCE_PERIODICIDAD AS Periodicidad,
    RCCE_DURACION_TRATAMIENTO AS DuracionTratamiento,
    RCCE_CONTADOR AS Contador,
    FRFR_IDVITAMEDICA AS IdFarmacia

FROM FIV_RCCE_RECETA_CONSULTA_ELECTRONICA WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE RCCE_ENVIO_DOMICILIO = '1'
ORDER BY RCCE_NID
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que englobar tu query en una CTE y añadir un row_number para así quedarte con la fecha más reciente, te explico:

La query final sería algo así

```
with mycte as (
SELECT
    RCCE_NID AS RecetaId,
    CASE (RCCE_ESTATUS) WHEN '0' THEN 'Recepción Vitamedica' ELSE 'Cotizar' END AS Estatus,
    RCCE_NOMBRES + ' ' + RCCE_APELLIDO_PATERNO + ' ' + RCCE_APELLIDO_MATERNO AS Derechohabiente,
    RCCE_ELEGIBILIDAD AS Elegibilidad,
    RCCE_FOLIO_RECETA AS FolioReceta,
    RCCE_TANTO_RECETA AS TantoReceta,
    RCCE_CODIGO_EAN AS CodigoEAN,
    RCCE_DESCRIPCION_MEDICAMENTO AS DescripcionMedicamento,
    RCCE_UNIDADES AS Unidades,
    RCCE_PREAUTORIZACION AS Preautorizacion,
    RCCE_FECHA_CONSULTA AS FechaConsulta,
    RCCE_COPAGO AS Copago,
    CASE (RCCE_TIPO_EMPLEADO) WHEN '0' THEN 'Funcionario' ELSE 'Empleado' END AS TipoEmpleado,
    CASE (RCCE_STATUS_EMPLEADO) WHEN '0' THEN 'Activo' ELSE 'Jubilado' END AS EstatusEmpleado,
    RCCE_NUMERO_TELEFONO AS NumeroTelefono,
    CASE (RCCE_TIPO_TELEFONO) WHEN '0' THEN 'Fijo' ELSE 'Móvil' END AS TipoTelefono,
    RCCE_CANTIDAD_TOMA AS CantidadToma,
    RCCE_PERIODICIDAD AS Periodicidad,
    RCCE_DURACION_TRATAMIENTO AS DuracionTratamiento,
    RCCE_CONTADOR AS Contador,
    FRFR_IDVITAMEDICA AS IdFarmacia
, row_number() over(partition by RCCE_NID order by FechaConsulta DESC) as rn
FROM FIV_RCCE_RECETA_CONSULTA_ELECTRONICA WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE RCCE_ENVIO_DOMICILIO = '1'
)
select * from mycte
WHERE rn=1
ORDER BY RCCE_NID
```

Basicamente, en la cte se asigna un numero de fila para cada RCE_NID repetido en la tabla por fecha descendiente, por lo que el numero de fila 1 siempre será el mayor (He cogido la columna RCE_NID porque creo que es la columna donde se repite el valor)

```
row_number() over(partition by RCCE_NID order by FechaConsulta DESC) as rn
```

Solo habría que aplicar un filtro cuando numero de fila sea 1 y ya no se muestran valores repetidos y obtienes el valor que deseas

```
select * from mycte
    WHERE rn=1
    ORDER BY RCCE_NID
```

Te dejo un otra pregunta que respondí sobre este tema, espero que te ayude.
[Big Query drop duplicates](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/310619/big-query-drop-duplicates/310629#310629)