# Big Query drop duplicates

Tags: sql

I have this table:

```
  date     |   ID  |  ID_2
2019-07-13 |  7901 |  AB1D
2019-11-13 |  6452 |  AB1D
2019-05-13 |  678D |  4PLD
```

I would like to get a table without duplicates of ID_2 but the date and ID that I would like to get is the ID which have the max(date)

Comment: Bienvenido. Estas en StackOverflow en español. Traduce la pregunta al idioma del sitio. También la puedes eliminar y hacerlo en el sitio de lengua inglesa.

Answer (score 1):

hola DataMath y bienvenido,

Te dejo una query que resuelve tu problema

```
with mycte as (
    select 
        [date],
        [ID],
        [ID_2],
        row_number() over(partition by ID_2 order by [date] DESC) as rn
    from #test
)
Select [date],[ID],[ID_2]
from mycte
where rn=1
```

Basicamente, en la cte se asigna un numero de fila para cada ID_2 repetido en la tabla por fecha descendiente, por lo que el numero de fila 1 siempre será el mayor
[image: cte query]

Solo habría que aplicar un filtro cuando numero de fila sea 1 y ya no se muestran valores repetidos y obtienes el valor de ID_2 que deseas

[image: query]